# pandas: groupby using specific class without filtering the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate farming growth probability with groupby, however, is it possible to have a specific class(state: WA) without filtering the rows?

i was able to calculate the probability with the codes below, however, it will filter the rows that are not WA, which makes it impossible to do further calculation that require those filtered states in the same dataframe.

```
df['all'] = (df[df["state"]=="WA"].groupby(['farm'])['place'].cumcount() + 1)

df['1'] = df['add'].loc[df.place == 1]

df = df[df["state"]=="WA"].groupby(['farm']).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0))

df['farm_growth%'] = (df['1'] / df['all'])
```

df sample:

```
'farm':['aaa','ggc','cdv','ddf','wes','jcj','jjw'],
'place':[1,4,5,8,7,10,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Regards Thank you

Update to the question:
My goal is to have the calculations of both "all states" and "state: WA" in the same dataframe.

@delimiter has provided the code for "all states". thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question well, but if you want to keep all the states in the calculation, just remove the following part in square brackets from the equation:

```
df[df["state"]=="WA"]
```

would become simply

```
df
```

or for the full sample:

```
df['all'] = (df.groupby(['farm'])['place'].cumcount() + 1)
df['1'] = df['add'].loc[df.place == 1]
df = df[df.groupby(['farm']).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0))
df['farm_growth%'] = (df['1'] / df['all'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. however,  I want to have the specific class( state: WA) without filtering out the rows for calculating the probabilities.

Comment: in short, it's wanting both 'all states' and 'only WA' calculations in the same dataframe.

Comment: That sounds self contradicting to me because we can't have "only X" and "X + Y" at once. Maybe it can be of a benefit for you to run calculations for X and for all separately, and then join your results into one dataframe.

Comment: thanks delimiter, that was what i thought, and i'm calculating them in two separating dataframe. Reason i wanted to have both in the same df is for comparison purposes. cheers